# Hibernate 1:n relation bringing null values

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes

Alocacao and Responsavel

I have a 1:n

Responsavel.class

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name="Responsavel")
public class Responsavel {

@Id
@Column(name="idResp")
private int idResp;

@Column(name="nomeResp")
private String nomeResp;

@Column(name="emailResp")
private String email;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="idGrupResp")
private GrupoResponsavel grupo;

@Column(name="idPovUser")
private int povUser;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="responsavel", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<TarefaBackLog> tarefa;

public Responsavel() {
    super();
}
//getters and setters
```

Alocacao.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "responsavel_alocacao")
public class Alocacao {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idRespAloc")
private int idAlocacao;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idResponsavel", referencedColumnName="idResp")
private Responsavel idResponsavel;

@JoinColumn(name="idPeriodo")
private PeriodoPov idPeriodo;

@Column(name="Alocacao")
private double alocacao;
//getters and setters
```

But when I try to get all the Alocacao objects with "findAll()", it brings me null values to idPeriodo and idResponsavel.. any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The values in the corresponding columns are null? Note that you're missing a ManyToOne or OneToOne annotation on idPeriodo.

Comment: No, the columns are both filled.. Thanks for notice about the @ManyToOne annotation.

Comment: Show us example data, and show us the code used to load the data.

Comment: Actually, @JBNizet, I put the Annotation and It worked.. Can you explain why?
Now It brought both objects.. But it was missing only one annotation

Comment: No, I can't explain it. I would have guessed an exception instead of simply getting null.

Comment: Weird.. btw, thanks! :D